# log4j setting log file name @ runtime not working

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We have a requirement in the application that the log file created shoud have a different name every time it executes (based on functionality + the current thread). I have seen the questions already posted in SO and tried to use the same method, but it is not working.

All the log statements are getting logged in "xyz.log" (specified in the log4j.properties). Only "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout" gets logged in abc.log (specified in the program). Any pointers to solve this will be very helpful.

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, MyLogger

log4j.appender.MyLogger=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.MyLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.MyLogger = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.additivity = false
log4j.appender.MyLogger.File=xyz.log
log4j.appender.MyLogger.MaxFileSize = 5MB
log4j.appender.MyLogger.MaxBackupIndex = 20
# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.MyLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t](%c:%L) - %m%n
```

**Java code**

```
    logger = Logger.getLogger(MyLoggerUtil.class);
    Layout layout = new PatternLayout("org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
    logger.removeAllAppenders();
    FileAppender appender = null;
    try {
        appender = new FileAppender(layout, "abc.log", false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.addAppender(appender);
    logger.setLevel((Level) Level.DEBUG);
    logger.debug("This is a debug test");
```

Comment: The constructor of `PatternLayout` expects a pattern not a class name. Sth. like the conversion pattern you used in the properties file.

Comment: Good to hear. I created an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `PatternLayout` expects a conversion pattern, like the one used in the `lo4j.properties`. So change the creation of the `Layout` to:

```
Layout layout = new PatternLayout("%d %5p [%t](%c:%L) - %m%n");
```

*Pattern taken from your `log4j.properties`*